# How to edit autostart applications?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, autostart

How can I reach the UI to configure the autostart applications in Ubuntu 11.10? Please don't tell me, I have to do it using the terminal or creating a starter on my own and please don't tell me, it is gone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the **Startup Applications** application. 
You can find it either by searching for it (both Unity and Gnome Shell allow you to quickly search for applications), or in the *Other* section of applications (this section you can access again from either Gnome Shell or Unity but also from the classic applications menu in Gnome 2.x)

Applications may be startup in other ways, such as commands in scripts and etc. It is probable that the application's startup you are trying to edit is not accessible from the application I suggested to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but: I know that tool and since switching to gnome-shell i don't find it anymore. it seems not to be installed. So how can i install it or edit autostart applications in another way?

Comment: Oh well, I didn't know myself this tool was removed! What is happening to Ubuntu! All the power tools are being removed :( If you want to autostart applications you can add their launchers to `~/.local/etc/autostart/`

Answer (score 0):

For the  "Informational Challenged" like myself, you can find the programs you are seeking to add to the **Startup Applications** application in your **Computer>File System>User>Bin** folder. They should be listed alphabetically. :)

Comment: I guess you are talking about the `/usr/bin/` path, but it may be misleading to say that all binaries are in that folder, for some are under `/usr/local/bin`, some under `/usr/sbin/`, etc. There is not a single route for all the executables.