# How can I make an application start up when I login?

Tags: command-line, login, startup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start applications at startup automatically in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-to-start-applications-at-startup-automatically-in-unity)
>   [How to edit autostart applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76402/how-to-edit-autostart-applications)

I want Terminal to start up right when i login. Is there a command? If so, I'm using **Bash**.

Comment: I know this is a duplicity, but still makes fun to answer it ;) Plus, none of the answers above has used as I have explained in my answer the drag&drop functionality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the Dash (press Super key, or "Windows" key) and type:

```
 Startup Applications
```

Open the resulted application.

Now open up the Dash again and this time type:

```
terminal
```

Now drag&drop the resulted application to the earlier opened *Startup Applications*.

Now  if you want you can test this by logout and log in again.

COnsider creating custom scripts and add them as comands in your *Startup Applications*

Answer (score 0):

For Gnome :

System ->Preferences ->Startup Applications (select your application there)

For Unity:

press Alt + F2 and select the application you want to appear on startup