# How to run a command at login?

Tags: command-line, login, startup, scripts

I need to run the following command (with real parameters) after login:

```
ssh -f user@example.com -L 54321:example.com:54321 -N
```

I need it only for my user, not all users on the machine. Also, I need it to run whether I login via the GUI or via SSH to a plain shell terminal. I would even like to know how to do this on machines without a GUI installed.

Where would I put the above line to be run as explained?

Comment: Have you looked at [this post](http://askubuntu.com/q/101197/62483)? Also, see [How to run scripts on start up?](http://askubuntu.com/q/814/62483)

Comment: @Lucio That doesn't address how to make it run for both graphical *and non-graphical* logins.

Comment: @EliahKagan Yes, I know that. I'm still looking other post, but those link will be useful to login via GUI.

Comment: @Lucio I found plenty of explanations how to do it for GUI *or* for shell *or* for all users. None of those are what I need.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Adding the command to the end of `~/.profile` should do the trick (where `~` represents your home directory).

*Not* `~/.bashrc`, which would make it run again every time a `bash` shell is started. In contrast, `.profile` is only run by interactive *login* shells. See [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html) and [`man sh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/sh.1.html) for more information.

Please note that this will run not just for GUI and SSH logins, but for all logins (or at least all interactive logins), including when you log on in a [virtual console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console).

Comment: It could work using `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: @Lucio If `.bash_profile` exists, then it overrides `.profile` *for `bash`*. I don't think the GUI uses a `bash` shell, though. I'll edit this to provide a link to `man sh` too (though I'm not sure it uses `sh`/`dash` either). `.profile` is universal (and typically, when `.bash_profile` exists, it's written so it `source`s `.profile`).

Comment: Great answer. If you want to find more information you can look [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/415403/1505348).

Comment: Where would I put it -just- for login to the GUI? Nothing else.

Comment: @FrankNocke For GUI only, you can start a script from a .desktop file in `~/.config/autostart/`. Or use the `gnome-session-properties` GUI.

Comment: @EliahKagan I have a little script that is meant to be run from the commandline and print something out. But if I put that in my .profile file, the script will run and I won't see the standard out.  How can I have the script open visibly? Say, to open a terminal first and then run the command?

Comment: Note that a `.desktop` file under `~/.config/autostart` can be created for you by the "Startup Applications" GUI. (Also, it might help in some cases to run the command within `bash`, e.g.: `bash -c "xkbcomp -I$HOME/.xkb ~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd $DISPLAY"` In this case, putting in the command without the `bash -c` part and double quotes did not work.)

Comment: I can run added program to `~/.profile` by ssh-ing to my localhost with: `ssh usename@localhost`

Comment: @mivk Thanks. I'll try: https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login#comment2643237_48327

Comment: Damn. It didn't work. I still needed to run `espanso restart` AGAIN after I logged in (after waking from sleep). I'll log an issue with Espanso. https://github.com/espanso/espanso/issues/1892