# Can cpulimit run a continuous background check?

Tags: services, startup-applications, cpulimit

I am suffering from occasional desktop freezes and am still investigating the cause. (Links forthcoming.) In the meantime I came across the following suggestion to `cpulimit` the `unity-panel-service`, which is working great so far!

```
sudo cpulimit -eb unity-panel-service -l 30
```

I would now like to configure cpulimit so that it:

- starts as soon as I log in
- runs in the background (no terminal required)
- if unity-panel-service restarts, it should discover and limit the new process

Is this possible?

*Note: I am aware that this is a workaround to a desktop bug. My question is primarily about using cpulimit, rather than the bug/workaround. When I have a moment I will provide links relating to the bug itself so discussion on that front can happen elsewhere.*

Answer (score 0):

[How to run a command at login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270049/how-to-run-a-command-at-login):

> Adding the command to the end of ~/.profile should do the trick (where ~ represents your home directory).
>
> ..you can start a script from a .desktop file in ~/.config/autostart/

OPTIONS
      -b  --background   run in background

```
sudo cpulimit -l 30 -b -p $(pgrep -o "unity-panel-service")
```

If you put a single & at the end of the command on a cli, it's supposed to run the job in the background. And it should find the new pid from the name every time. You can check if its running by:

```
pgrep -o "cpulimit"
```

Or create a bash script from it and make the script executable and set it to auto-run using autostart in Ubuntu.