# How to make xrandr customization permanent in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: 15.10, xrandr

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf` is not present on Ubuntu 15.10
what should I have to edit?

- Video Card: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]: Wrestler [Radeon HD 6320]
- Driver: X.Org X server - AMD/ATI display driver wrapper by xserver- xorg-video-ati
- Monitor: Samsung s19b150n

The command(s) I run:

```
cvt 1360 768
xrandr --newmode "1360x768_60.00" 84.75 1360 1432 1568 1776 768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-0 1360x768_60.00
```

Comment: How did you make the customization ? Do you have a command you ran ? xorg.conf was deprecated years ago.

Comment: I made the customization because of undetected resolutions.
I used the "xrandr --newmode ..." command and then "xrandr --addmode..." command

Comment: That's not what I needed, if you give me your `exact` command that you run to make the changes, I will show you how to run it automaticly at boot, so your resolution will set when you start Ubuntu..

Answer (score 0):

You can script the commands you ran and run it at login or you can edit xorg.conf

See [How to run a command at login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270049/how-to-run-a-command-at-login)

and http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/use-xrandr-to-set-a-screen-resolution/

Some of the graphical tools should do this for you (set a resolution) options  lxrandr , grandr, the grandr applet, ARandR, and Krandr.

The graphical tools may not if you need to add modes, hard to say, need a better idea of what you are running and what happens when you reboot.

If you need help, post your hardware, what driver you are using, and the exact commands you ran and we can convert them or make suggestions for xorg.conf

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --newmode "1360x768_60.00" 84.75 1360 1432 1568 1776 768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-0 1360x768_60.00
```

See [How to run a command at login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270049/how-to-run-a-command-at-login) for running it at login.

Comment: Video Card: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]: Wrestler [Radeon HD 6320]  

Driver: X.Org X server - AMD/ATI display driver wrapper by xserver-  xorg-video-ati  

Monitor: Samsung s19b150n  

The command I run:  
    cvt 1360 768  
    xrandr --newmode "1360x768_60.00" 84.75 1360 1432 1568 1776 768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync  
    xrandr --addmode DVI-0 1360x768_60.00

Comment: Video Card: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]: Wrestler [Radeon HD 6320]


Driver: X.Org X server - AMD/ATI display driver wrapper by xserver- xorg-video-ati  


Monitor: Samsung s19b150n  


The command I run:  


cvt 1360 768  


xrandr --newmode "1360x768_60.00" 84.75 1360 1432 1568 1776 768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync  


xrandr --addmode DVI-0 1360x768_60.00

Comment: so run those commands at login.

Comment: where may I put those commands? into the .bash_login?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/270049/how-to-run-a-command-at-login

Comment: Link fixed domain changed from bodhizazen.net to bodhizazen.com