# Set a hook on eCryptfs mount

Tags: mount, automount, ecryptfs

I want to run several commands as root after my eCryptfs is mounted on my login. Can I somehow set a hook for that? Can I do it with systemd?

What I want to achieve is to mount automatically on login a disk image that lays in the encrypted home directory.

Answer (score 0):

An already encrypted home? Then you can use the regular "run at login" methods but using `sudo`, like:

- Just put the commands in `~/.profile`
  See [How to run a command at login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270049/how-to-run-a-command-at-login)
- Use a .desktop file in `~/.config/autostart`
  See [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

Comment: No, the fact is that I want to run the command as root, and I'm not mistaken mount of eCryptfs if done with root privileges, so if I can just call it in the same context I'll get what I need. I want to run it as root, but I want to run it after eCryptfs mount. That's the complexity.

Comment: Are you familiar with sudo? It can run things as root, called by authorized users, and these methods are designed to run after the user logs in. What's stopping them from working?

Comment: sudo asks for a password and I want it to be automatic with no user interference, is it possible?

Comment: You can configure `sudo` to not ask for a password, for all or only a few commands. Check it's `man` pages and I'm sure there are answers about it on this site too. Good luck!