# How to startup a script automatically after login

Tags: 16.04, command-line, server

I Have a Ubuntu Headless Server and I want to run a basic script after I login how can I configure my server to run the script automatically after login?
Script:

```
clear
echo "Hello $USER"
echo "Today is \c ";date
echo "Number of user login : \c" ; who | wc -l
echo "Calendar"
cal
exit 0
```

Comment: You log into this server as a user with own home directory? And how do you log in? via SSH or locally?

Comment: Yes i login as a user with a own home directory and via SSH

Comment: and it only should execute once, when you login?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what it needs to do

Comment: See my answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add those lines at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file which will get executed when you login.

I'm talking about the `~/.bashrc` serverside. When you have added your lines and `logout` and `ssh` back in these lines will get executed. You can leave out the last line of your script.

If the `~/.bashrc` does not exist you can simply create it or even better copy it:

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc
```

and make sure your `~/.profile` file contains the following lines:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Where is the `.bashrc` file located?

Comment: In `~` of your user, if its not existing you can create it and make sure that the `~/.profile` includes it.

Comment: Found it! Should i add a reference to where the file is located or the code of the script directly?

Comment: You can add your lines directly  at the end of the `.bashrc` file just leave out the exit line (e.g. the last line you posted as script above).  And if you ever need a fresh `.bashrc` file you can copy it from `/etc/skel`

Comment: doesn't works on my 18.04.3, works by add in ~/.profile like explain in https://askubuntu.com/questions/270049/how-to-run-a-command-at-login

Answer (score 0):

Just worked for me the simplest way:

`sudo nano ~/.bash_profile`

Append any command or script in the end:

```
echo "Hello $USER"
echo "Today is \c ";date
echo "Number of user login : \c" ; who | wc -l
echo "Calendar"
cal
```

I intentionally omitted `exit 0` command because it exists from ssh automatically, so you will be unable to stay logged in.
(Tested on Ubuntu 20.4)