# Can not disable wakeup on opening lid

Tags: acpi

On my Lenovo T440p with Ubuntu 20.10 - Regolith-desktop I have the issue, that I can't disable the wakeup on opening the laptop lid.

I already tried the solution presented in most instructions of changing the file in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`. This didn't work. I could also not find any setting in the BIOS/UEFI.

Since I figured out the solution and couldn't find it anywhere, I present it here, in case anyone else has the same problem.

Comment: Although not implemented in an Ubuntu system, you can check and adapt this alternative to the above answer using a systemd service: https://github.com/szaffarano/nix-dotfiles/pull/86/files

Answer (score 0):

Call `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup`. This will look like this:

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node

LID       S4    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
SLPB      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0E:00
IGBE      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:19.0
EXP2      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.1
EXP3      S4    *disabled
XHCI      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
EHC1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
```

By writing i.e. `LID` to this file you can change the status:

```
root@machine # echo 'LID' >> /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

If you call `cat` again like before, you will see, that `LID` is `*disabled` now. Writing `LID` again to it, enables it again. The change is immediate.

Unfortunately, this change is not permanent. For this purpose, you can create a shell script, which is executed every time you start up your computer:

Make a new file, i.e.

```
root@machine # nano disableWakeup.sh
```

Paste this content into it

```
result=$(cat /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep 'enabled' | grep -o $1)
if [ "$result" != "" ]
then
echo "$result is enabled"
echo $1 >> /proc/acpi/wakeup 
echo "Disabled $1"
fi
```

Now, you have to make this file executable

```
root@machine # chmod 755 disableWakeup.sh
```

After this you can call the script by `./disableWakeup.sh LID`. This disables wakeup by LID-Switch. But you can replace `LID` by any other trigger, i.e. `./disableWakeup.sh EHC1`.

To execute it automatically, there are different ways, described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up), [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-run-script-on-startup-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-server-desktop) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270049/how-to-run-a-command-at-login), also others. I prefer adding a line at the end of the file /etc/bash.bashrc

```
/location/of/the/scrip/i.e./opt/loginScript/disableWakeup.sh
```

This is then called every time, you open a shell. More often than needed, but it works.