# How do I setup Ubuntu to boot in the morning and play music?

Tags: 12.04, boot

Is there a way to boot my computer in the morning and play music without turning it on? It's not that easy to find anything on Google because I don't have problems with booting. I'd rather like to improve the way my computer boots.

Comment: If any of the answers below helped you, please accept the answer that did.

Answer (score 5):

You have basically two **options** to get a timer-controlled auto-boot with

1. In your BIOS, search for the **timer-controlled Auto-Bootup-Option** and select it. Some BIOSes have this function, BUT NOT all! This depends on the BIOS manufacturer and version. Here you also can define **when** the computer will boot up.
2. In your BIOS, you select the **Wake-on-LAN** option. Now you want to configure your Router so that the router wakes the PC everyday **at the time you want** via Wake-on-LAN. It could be that your Router doesn't support this function, but it should.

Now, you can configure your Ubuntu so that you have an **auto-login** and a **startup-script** that plays the music.

I hope you understand my answer and that it is helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not afraid to auto-boot to some user without a password, try **Wake on Plan** app to switch on your computer at a desired time. Currently it's available from PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~xintx-ua/+archive/wakeonplan

In a week, it should be available from Ubuntu's extras repository:

https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps/1188/

You only need to select which player to autostart with:

[How to edit autostart applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76402/how-to-edit-autostart-applications)

For example:

`vlc /path/to/music`

(don't forget to escape spaces like this: `vlc /home/user/folder\ name\ with\ spaces` )

Answer (score 0):

There's this software in the Ubuntu Software Center called 'gWakeOnLan'. Install it.

Then add a startup script on your machine to play music when the computer is switched on.

Note: The machine needs to be turned off with Wake On LAN magic packet enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any software to wake on host by LAN (e.g., from your phone or any other PC). 
Whatever you use, you will also need to set up appropriate script to play music after start up.

[This article on my own blog](http://lukasz-lademann.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-set-up-wol-wake-on-lan-on-thin.html) describes how to automatically wake up Ubuntu and shut it down when you don't need to use the server. So for you, Ubuntu starts to play music and will turn off after that. It depends on your needs for how to configure the script to turn off.

Answer (score 0):

here is what everyone has been looking 4  it took me 4 hours to figure ouy between the coding here my own coding and my grandpas coding

**sh -c "sleep 1m; banshee --hide & sleep 20; banshee --play"**   the 1m stands for a timeout

which is recommended you can change that

you need to put it in your start up applications  this will take care of the music part of your problem